# Загрузка и выгрузка url изображения в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Вопрос в следующем. есть код загрузки абсолютного пути

```html
if((!empty($_FILES["userfile"])) && ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0)) {
  // проверяем, что файл это изображение JPEG и его размер не больше 350кб
  $filename = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "png") && ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "image/png") && 
    ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] < 350000000)) {
    // путь для сохранения файла
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
      // проверяем, файл с таким названием уже есть на сервере
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        // переместить загруженный файл в новое место
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           echo "Прелестно, файл был загружен: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Произошла ошибка при загрузке файла!";
        }
      } else {
         echo "Ошибка: файл ".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]." уже существует";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Ошибка при загрузке файла, изображение не .png или больше чем 350кб.";
  }
} else {
 echo "Ошибка: файл не загружен!";
```

В БД записывается все корректно в виде /var/www/..../upload/xxx.png
Возникает проблема с выгрузкой и размещением на сайте. Пример кода:

```html
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($resultat4))
{
  echo '<div class="main_text" style="float:right;">';
   echo '<div class="head">' .$array['name']. '</div><br>';
   echo '<img src='.$array['file'].'>'; 
      
      ......
```

Собственно в src прописывается фул адрес /var/www....
Подскажите, можно ли его обрезать до нужного ./upload/ или же что стоит изменить в коде. Заранее огромное спасибо

Comment: не пишите в бд путь для сохранения файла, а пишите просто имя самого файла

Answer (score 1):

Не весь код предоставлен, нет сохранения пути к файлу в Базу данных.

Но это решение корректный ответ сервера при загрузке изображения, рекомендую загружать в бд файл не от корня, а от папки uploads. 
А ещё лучше - это хранит название файла в чистом виде!

Замени с

```
$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
// проверяем, файл с таким названием уже есть на сервере
if (!file_exists($newname)) {
    // переместить загруженный файл в новое место
    if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
       echo "Прелестно, файл был загружен: ".$newname;
    } else {
       echo "Произошла ошибка при загрузке файла!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Ошибка: файл ".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]." уже существует";
}
```

На

```
$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
$path = '/upload/'.$filenam;
// проверяем, файл с таким названием уже есть на сервере
if (!file_exists($newname)) {
    // переместить загруженный файл в новое место
    if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
        echo "Прелестно, файл был загружен: ".$path;
    } else {
        echo "Произошла ошибка при загрузке файла!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Ошибка: файл ".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]." уже существует";
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Внес изменения, но в БД все также записывается полный путь /var/www/...

Comment: @KirillSawoyen приложите часть кода, отвечающую за запись данных в БД

Comment: добавил. в рабочем примере указано $photo = $newname;
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO main_table(name, adr, email, city, message, tel, категория, file, fax, tel_gor ) VALUES ('$name', '$adr', '$email', '$ind', '$message', '$tel', '$var', '$photo', '$fax', '$tel_gor')");

Comment: @KirillSawoyen Замените с $photo = $newname; на $photo = $path;